# Static per-enum data: constructor, set in initialiser or override getter?

Tags: java, coding-style, enum

I have an enum with > 10 items each having 8 static properties. Contrived example:

```java
enum JavaTypes {
    INTEGER,
    BOOLEAN,
    STRING,
    ...;

    boolean isPrimitive() {
    }

    boolean isNumeric() {
    }
    ...
}
```

I am trying to find the most readable and maintainable (easy to add properties) style.

1. The standard override getters doesn't work very well, as each enum body gets quite long and it's difficult to compare the same property across items.
2. Setting all the properties in the constructor. Plagued by the problem of which argument is which. I tried to align the arguments into a table, but defeated by the hard 120-char limit we have.
3. Non-final fields and instance initialiser: e.g.

   ```java
   INTEGER {{ primitive = true; numeric = true; }},

   boolean primitive, numeric;

   boolean isPrimitive() {
       return primitive;
   }
   ```

   This feels a bit dirty though.

Is 3 acceptable? Is there any better option.

Edit:

Just to clarify, not all of the properties are booleans.

Comment: `boolean isPrimitive() {
        return [conditional expression evaluating to bool];
    }`  -- Skip the private members, unless you want to use composite expressions like `return primitive || numeric;`

Comment: I've updated my answer to try to address "Just to clarify, not all of the properties are Booleans" - does the improved version address that?  If not, can you give an example of what you need to address there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One other option would be to use a second enum and a varargs constructor, along with an `EnumSet`:

```java
enum JavaType {
    INTEGER(TypeProperty.PRIMITIVE, TypeProperty.NUMERIC),
    BOOLEAN(TypeProperty.PRIMITIVE),
    STRING(),
    /* ... */;

    private EnumSet<TypeProperty> properties;
    private JavaType(TypeProperty... properties) {
        this.properties = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(properties));
    }

    public boolean isPrimitive() {
        return properties.contains(TypeProperty.PRIMITIVE);
    }

    public boolean isNumeric() {
        return properties.contains(TypeProperty.NUMERIC);
    }
    /* ... */

    private enum TypeProperty {
        PRIMITIVE,
        NUMERIC,
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

This has the benefit of not requiring to specify a bunch of false values in a constructor (the problem with #2) but also doesn't require a bunch of inner classes for each enum.  The `TypeProperty` enum doesn't even need to be visible outside of `JavaType` for this to work.

Alternatively, `TypeProperty` can be made public and there can be a `is(TypeProperty)` method.  Whether you want this or not depends on how you plan on using `JavaType`; it can be convenient to expose it (eg for making a `allWith(TypeProperty)` method) but if it's not something you'd be likely to use outside, don't expose it.  Whether or not you actually want it depends on how you're going to be using your enum.

If `TypeProperty` is exposed, it could be combined with a [static import](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/static-import.html) so that you can just reference the enum constant names from within the type.  This can help with readability if used well, but be careful with it.  `TypeProperty` must be exposed to be imported, although it can still be mostly private if needed (it can still be within `JavaType` if needed, it just can't be `private`).  Here's a sample:

```java
package com.example;
import static com.example.TypeProperty.*;

enum JavaType {
    INTEGER(PRIMITIVE, NUMERIC),
    BOOLEAN(PRIMITIVE),
    STRING(),
    /* ... */;

    private EnumSet<TypeProperty> properties;
    private JavaType(TypeProperty... properties) {
        this.properties = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(properties));
    }

    public boolean isPrimitive() {
        return properties.contains(PRIMITIVE);
    }

    public boolean isNumeric() {
        return properties.contains(NUMERIC);
    }
    /* ... */
}

enum TypeProperty {
    PRIMITIVE,
    NUMERIC,
    /* ... */
}
```

> Just to clarify, not all of the properties are booleans.

If you have a few non-Boolean properties, you can put them at the start of the constructor and then follow it with the varargs param.  You still can run into the unlabeled issue, but it lets you organize it more.  Say, something like this:

```java
enum JavaType {
    INTEGER("int", Integer.class, TypeProperty.PRIMITIVE, TypeProperty.NUMERIC),
    BOOLEAN("boolean", Boolean.class, TypeProperty.PRIMITIVE),
    STRING("String", String.class),
    /* ... */;

    private String name;
    private Class<?> representationClass;
    private EnumSet<TypeProperty> properties;
    private JavaType(String name, Class<?> representationClass, TypeProperty... properties) {
        this.name = name;
        this.representationClass = representationClass;
        this.properties = EnumSet.copyOf(Arrays.asList(properties));
    }
    /* ... code from before ... */
}
```

If you have a lot of non-Boolean properties, then it gets a lot harder to organize.  At that point, approach #3 may be more reasonable, or alternatively you could combine approach #1 and varargs params.

Comment: Great answer.  I would take this one step further by changing all the isXxx, isYyy methods to a single  `is(TypeProperty)`.  That means TypeProperty means to be visible.

Comment: Very interesting solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a huge fan of enums over using the Typesafe Enum pattern for this reason among others.  The main advantage with using the built in enum feature is that you can use them in switch statements but I tend to prefer polymorphism anyway.

Anyway, another way to do this which uses the 'switchability' of enums is as follows.  It's kind of ugly but so are enums in general:

```
public class EnumHolder
{
  public enum JavaTypes {
    INTEGER,
    BOOLEAN,
    STRING;

    boolean isPrimitive() {
      return EnumHolder.isPrimitive(this);
    }
  }

  private static final boolean isPrimitive(JavaTypes type) {
    switch (type) {
      case INTEGER:
      case BOOLEAN:
        return true;
      default:
        return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Switching on enums is nice, but why do you need the second `EnumHolder` class?  You could also use `switch (this)` within the enum itself.

Comment: @Pokechu22 True.  I guess I always use them within another class.  It would work the same, as you suggest.